# Lithium PHP routes not working

Tags: php, routes, lithium

I'm following the quickstart guide for Lithium: http://li3.me/docs/manual/quickstart

I created my posts Model in /var/www/my_app/app/models/Posts.php

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

class Posts extends \lithium\data\Model {
}

?>
```

I created my posts Controller in /var/www/my_app/app/controllers/PostsController.php

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

class PostsController extends \lithium\action\Controller {

    public function index() {
            return array('foo' => 'bar', 'title' => 'Posts');
    }
}

?>
```

And I created my View in /var/www/my_app/app/views/posts/index.html.php

```
Lithium is less dense than <?=$foo;?>ium.
```

The quickstart guide then says that I should be able to view my posts index page by going to

```
http://localhost/my_app/posts
```

but I get a

```
Not Found

The requested URL /my_app/posts was not found on this server.
```

However, if I go to just

```
http://localhost/my_app
```

the default home page that comes with Lithium  is displayed.

So I tried fixing the problem by adding this line to my /var/www/my_app/config/routes.php file:

```
Router::connect('/posts', 'Posts::index');
```

But I get the same Not Found error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure that `mod_rewrite` is installed *and enabled* in your Apache.

Also check that the `.htaccess` file is present and `allow_override` is properly set for the virtualHost, otherwise `.htaccess` files will be ignored.

For further information, check the [troubleshooting](http://lithify.me/docs/manual/getting-started/troubleshooting.wiki) section in the documentation

Comment: I ran this command to enable mod_rewrite: "sudo a2enmod rewrite" and I  modified "/etc/apache2/sites-available/default" and set AllowOverride to "All".

Comment: Argh! can't believe I forgot to check my vhost directive for this. Thanks for the reminder, it did the trick!  :)

Answer (score 0):

A little bit further in the [Routing documentation](http://lithify.me/docs/manual/handling-http-requests/routing.wiki), the parameters of the `Router::connect()` method are explained more fully. The portion after the `::` should be the name of the action called by the route; in your case `index` (or perhaps nothing, if there's a default set for the indexAction; not familiar with Lithium). You derive the "name" by removing the suffix `Action` from your Controller's method name. I suggest exploring the Routing documentation more fully to save yourself headaches in the future.

Comment: Okay that makes more sense now.
I changed my route to 
    Router::connect('/posts', 'Posts::index');
But I still get the same Not Found error.

Comment: Are you sure that `mod_rewrite` is installed and enabled? Is your `.htaccess` file present and is `allow_override` properly set? Check the section on [troubleshooting](http://lithify.me/docs/manual/getting-started/troubleshooting.wiki)

Comment: @thaJeztah yes mod_rewrite was the issue do you want to write that as the answer so I can select it.